# Security constraint <url-pattern> acting weirdly - websphere

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, websphere, security

I am testing security constraints for certain URLs. I feel *url pattern* is acting weird. I want access restricted whatever comes after `ServletSecurityTest(webapproot)/`. But, after deploying war file in websphere, even `ServletSecurityTest(webapproot)` itself is restricted. why ?

**For example:**

I wanted this `http//ravi-pc:9080/ServletSecurityTest/testSecurity.do` to be restricted. That is alright. But even `http//ravi-pc:9080/ServletSecurityTest` is restricted. why ?

Any ideas ?

**web.xml**

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Servlet Security Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
</security-role>
```

**Servlet**

```
@WebServlet(name="SecurityTestServlet", urlPatterns={"/testSecurity.do"})
public class SecurityTestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.getWriter().write("Only Administrators can see this...");

    }

}
```

Comment: found the explanation. Nice one >> http://stackoverflow.com/a/10667527/2093375

Answer (score 1):

`<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` Means all the URLs after the `/`.

`/testSecurity.do and /testSecurity` both fall under the pattern you have specified.

Try `<url-pattern>/*.do</url-pattern>` and see.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my Q. My Q is why my web app root folder is also restricted, which is `http//ravi-pc:9080/ServletSecurityTest`

Comment: / means root web app location. So anything after that is also effected. Check the servlet specification for the exact spec info. http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/

Answer (score 0):

By mentioning `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` you ensured that root folder is also secured. 
I faced similar issue, and resolved this my changing folder structure as below.

```
<security-constraint>
     <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>Servlet Security Resources</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/ServletSecurityTest/*</url-pattern>
         <url-pattern>/auth/*</url-pattern>
     </web-resource-collection>
     <auth-constraint>
         <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
     </auth-constraint>
```

All authentication contents are moved to auth folder or create role based folders and provide different access to these folders.